# How to point DNS records to Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-ec2, amazon-aws

I just created a new environment with AWS and uploaded a .zip file into elastic beanstalk. I used to have a friend's server host my site instead of GoDaddy so I changed my custom DNS name servers from pointing to my friend's server to GoDaddy's. AWS told me that I need I need to add a CNAME record on GoDaddy and I did.

The alias is `lance` and the host is `lance-env.elasticbeanstalk.com`. I know that this change can take 24-48 hours to take effect but it's been a day already and when I go to [my site](http://twitterrecovery.com), a default page from GoDaddy appears. I'm very new to AWS and would just like to find a way for AWS to host my site other than using Route53.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're wanting to do here: the URL for "my site", which is a root domain (not a subdomain) is currently pointed to an IP address at GoDaddy. The host `lance-env.elasticbeanstalk.com` is pointed to an IP at Amazon, but not returning. Either does the root `elasticbeanstalk.com`. First you'll need the root `elasticbeanstalk.com` to return your website - same with `lance-env.elasticbeanstalk.com`. Then you can direct the root for "my site" to that, or vice versa using a CNAME.

Comment: @dan elasticbeanstalk.com is owned by Amazon.  See: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that your DNS settings are correct.

```
$ ping twitterrecovery.com
ping: unknown host twitterrecovery.com

$ dig twitterrecovery.com
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;twitterrecovery.com.       IN  A
```

No CNAME record has actually been in your domain records.

---

Unless you use a `www` subdoman, you are going to have problems when not using route53.  If you set your root domain to a CNAME, email at your domain name will stop working.   You can either:

- Put the CNAME on the www subdomain
- OR, use route53 which is the only DNS provider that I know that allows "alias" records.  It basically allows you to specify a CNAME, but queries it server side and returns an A record.